# Maven assembly plugin - excluding jar file not working

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

kacaps*.jar is added as dependency but while building the war file i do not want the kcaps*.jar to be included as it is already in runtime shared library on server. Can not add scope as provided because then local setup won't work.
Any suggestions?

Dependency section
        
            com.bcbsks
            kcaps
            ${aces.version}
            provided</scope> -->
            jar

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>source</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>

                        <dependencySets>
                            <dependencySet>
                                <outputDirectory>${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
                                <unpack>true</unpack>
                                <scope>runtime</scope>
                            <unpackOptions>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/kcaps*.jar</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </unpackOptions>        
                            </dependencySet>
                        </dependencySets>

                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                                <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                                <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/kcaps*.jar</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>

                        <!--           <filters>
                                    <filter>${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/kcaps*.jar</filter>
                                  </filters>         -->    
                        <!--            <excludes>
                                <exclude>${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/kcaps*.jar</exclude>
                              </excludes>        -->            
                            <webXml>${webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>


                            <descriptorRefs>war-with-dependencies</descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: *Can not add scope as provided because then local setup won't work. Any suggestions?* Why? This shouldn't happen. You should have those JAR provided by your local setup also.

Comment: As I mentioned I have shared library on the server and jenkins build job which copy the Jar files to the shared library based on POM file. For local setup it will be manual work to copy Jar every time as there are lot of dependent modules and version changes every monthly release.

Comment: Something is wrong. Fix your _real_ issue. Your question is not the real issue you're having. If those JAR are provided, then they should be provided for all environments. Conversely, if they're not provided, then they should be not provided for all environment. Be consistent.